# Display records from MYSQL using PHP only if insert occurs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The PHP function given below displays the latest inserts one the page is loaded, but I want to  refresh the data every time a row is inserted. I have heard of ajax, but I am not very familiar with it. Can anyone give me some guidance?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="OPlayout.css"/>
    <title>Operator View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="whole">
        <section id="mid_section"></br>
            <h2>Requests</h2></br>

            <?php include 'functions.php';
                currentRequests();
            ?>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**PHP function :**

```
function currentRequests(){
    //Include database connection file
    include 'databaseConnect.php';

    //Call global function to connect to db
    $connection = connectToDatabase();

    $queryToRun = "SELECT * FROM table_user_request
    WHERE 1=1
    AND date(entry_date) = date(now())
    ORDER BY entry_date DESC";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $queryToRun);

    //Create a table to store the results
    echo "<table border = '1' style='max-width:1180px;font-size: 14px;' >
        <tr>
            <td style='width:120px '>Name</td>
            <td style='width:120px '>Location</td>
            <td style='width: 20px '># of Riders</td>
            <td style='width:120px '>Destination</td>
            <td style='width:150px '>Email</td>
            <td style='width:100px '>Telephone</td>
            <td style='width:50px '>Date</td>
            <td style='width:50px '>Status</td>
            <td style='width: 60px '>Vehicle</td>
            <td style='width:50px '>Cancellation Reason</td>
            <td style='width: 60px '>Priority</td>
        </tr>";

    //Print records until done
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        //echo("<table border = '1' style='width:1200px'>");
        //Output results found in the database
        echo("<tr>
            <td>" . $row['1']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['3']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['5']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['4']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['8']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['9']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['10']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['11']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['12']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['13']
                . "</td> <td>" . $row['14'] . "</td>
            </tr>");
    }

    echo("</table>");
}
```

Comment: how does one insert a new record? I dont see the HTML/JS code for that. Is it done on the same page?

Comment: It is done on a different page which a call the user interface. Once a record is inserted through the user interface, I want to be able to display it on the operator's end without having to refresh the whole page.

Comment: What you can do is compare every few minutes if there are more or less rows in the database and update your page accordingly.

Comment: Do you recommend using php->usleep to cause the delay and execute the code using a loop?

Comment: No, have an AJAX call every few minutes that checks for new data.

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip: You don't need `1=1` in your SQL, it will fetch all possible rows on default. I'm fairly sure that if you have your column data types set up properly, you don't need to cast `date()`.

```
SELECT * FROM table_user_request
        WHERE date(entry_date) = date(now())
        ORDER BY entry_date DESC
```

I'm unsure of really what the question is, do you want a delay between rows being loaded? What do you mean by refresh the data? What Ajax would do for you is allow data to be dynamically loaded **without** reloading the page.

Comment: The code is working fine since it already pulls and displays records from the database, but I want to display the data on the page every time there is an INSERT into the table w/o having to refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Every few seconds you could ask the server if there are new rows in the table, if there aren't, do nothing. If there are, ask the server to return the new rows as JSON data, then append the new data into the table. All of this could be done with jQuery. GET's will do it all! More on [jQuery here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp).

Comment: I have used set interval() from jquery before, but I am not very familiar with the language. I will take a look anyways to decide which is the best way to go. Thank you

Comment: jQuery is very easy to use! It's simplified JavaScript. w3schools explains it very well, and only a remote JS file link is needed to use it. Once you get started, setInterval for a few seconds, each time call a $.GET to see if there's data to be displayed!